# How to grab the Contents Which updated by JavaScript WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser web = (WebBrowser)sender;
    richTextBox1.Text = web.DocumentText;
}
```

above is sample code.
 it's giving all Text of Current Open, if contents is updated by JavaScript, it visible but Document.Text not update.

Please Help guys

Comment: What is being updated with "javascript"?. You should first wait for it to run the javascript code or run it yourself. then you can see the document. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Javascript runs fundamentally asynchronous from the web browser state as observable in your program.  There are no events that indicate that it is running or stopped.  The only observable side-effect is the modifications it makes to the DOM.  A timer that's "long" enough is the typical hack to work around this.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Use the following sample code:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
string content = doc.body.innerText;
```

Also, add mshtml to the references of your project (if you dont know how to add the refernce, just google it).

Actually, whenever you use this code, the value in the `doc` variable is the updated version of the contents of the webbrowser.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the javascript that is executing on the page which is modifying the content is happening *after* the DocumentCompleted event; Perhaps you can try a different event such as 'Invalidated'.

The WebBrowser.DocumentText also many not reflect any changes to the DOM, and you may need to navigate the DOM through the WebBrowser.Document property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx